# Invariant Subspaces of a representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have read that a representation $D(g)$ of the elements of a group $G$ is reducible if it has an invariant subspace. In terms of a projection operator $P$ this corresponds to

$$ PD(g)P = D(g)P $$

for all $g \in G$. I cannot work out how the above condition is formed. My interpretation of an invariant subspace $W \subset V $, is that for all $D(g)$ and $u \in W$,

$$ D(g)u = v \in W, $$

and if we project onto the subspace using $P$ this will not change anything

$$ PD(g)u = Pv = v \in W. $$

So I should get $PD(g) = D(g)$. I am not sure where the right multiplication by $P$ comes from in my first equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your own characterization for an invariant subspace is more correct than the one you quoted. Such a projection $P$ only exists if there is another invariant subspace $W'$ which is *complementary* to $W$ (where $W' = \ker P$).

In characteristic zero for finite groups, such a $W'$ always exists.

Comment: It's not true even in characteristic zero. You need some hypotheses on the group, e.g. that it is finite.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan of course, thank you!